# BSON for Binary data

Tags: visual-c++, bson

how can I put a `char* buffer` which is having binary data (read from a image file) to BSON format. I am trying it in vc++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to add it as binary data using [BsonObjBuilder's appendBinData method](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/2.1.0/classmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_obj_builder.html#a720696f5ac79c620fe15056786c96108).